# jQuery IE6 and 7 error

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
$('#main-nav a').mouseover(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#subnav ul." + name).show();
})
```

Basically the code just gets the value of the rel attribute of a link when it is hovered over and then makes any ul with a class of the same value appear.

This code works fine in any other browser apart from IE6 and 7 which gives me the following errors:

1. exception thrown and not caught (in my jquery 1.4.4 file)
2. object doesn't support this property or method (in my jquery script that iv wrote)

It is something to do with the fact that iv used a variable in my selector, if i dont use a variable I don't get these errors.

The thing is though I need to put the variable in there in order for it to work, does anyone know of a better way to do this that won't cause these errors?

Thanks

Comment: You need to first check that the concatenation of the string and variable to create the selector is always successful, by printing it out.

Comment: The alert(name) is correct, there are three different values it can be (sat, usa or jap) so when these are concatenated the selector will be #subnav ul.sat, #subnav ul.usa or #subnav ul.jap which is what I want the selector to be. if I just type one of these selectors in manually without messing round with variables I don't get the errors though so I am baffled!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `'#main-nav a'` returns a collection of `<a>` objects. Have you tried iterating the result with `each`?

```
$.each($('#main-nav a'), function (index, element) {
    element.mouseover(function() { 
        var name = $(this).attr("rel"); 
        $("#subnav ul." + name).show(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Well actually its fixed it in IE7, but IE6 is still getting the errors! I hate that browser with a passioN!

Comment: Isn't that what jQuery does internally anyway?

Comment: @geoffs3310: I changed the iteration method, try if the new one works. If it doesn't then you probably need to attack this problem step by step. After getting jQuery up and running in IE6, verify the correctness of code from bottom up -- first test the selector, then the size of the collection, after that try to get the iteration working .. you get the idea.